# Is it possible to have an attached property that cast the type to the type that is needed in the view model?

Tags: c#, attached-properties

Until now, to can know in the view model the selected items in a list view, I am using an attached property.

This is the code:

```
public class ListViewSelectedItemsBehavior : Behavior<ListView>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged;
    }
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged;
    }

    void AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<object>(AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Cast<object>());
    }


    public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems"
            , typeof(ObservableCollection<object>)
            , typeof(ListViewSelectedItemsBehavior)
            ,
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
}
```

The problem is that the ObservableCollection is of type object, but in the view model I need to work with a collection of the specific type that it needs. So I have to do something like that in the view model:

```
partial void OnMyCollectionSelectedItemsChanged(ObservableCollection<object> value)
{
    _myCollectionSelectedItemsTyped!.Clear();
    if (value != null) _myCollectionSelectedItemsTyped.AddRange(value.Cast<string>());
}


private List<string> _myCollectionSelectedItemsTyped = new List<string>();
```

I was thinking that if in the attached property I could do in some way to use a generic type or another way to avoid to have to add this code in the view models, it would be a good improvement.  But really I don't know how could I do it.

Thanks.